# proof of $\bigcup\limits_{n\geq2}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\tilde{B}(a,\frac{1}{n})\right) = \mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{a\} $

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following. I understand that the equation is true but I am lost in how to prove that the equation is true.

$\bigcup\limits_{n\geq2}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\tilde{B}(a,\frac{1}{n})\right) = \mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{a\} $

Comment: Does $\widetilde{B}(a,r)=\{x\in\Bbb R^n:\|x-a\|\color{red}{\le} r\}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes.

Comment: Hi.. I think you can work with the complement of this union with respect to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove it by showing that each side is a subset of the other. In one direction this is immediate: since $\{a\}\subseteq\widetilde{B}\left(a,\frac1n\right)$ for each $n\ge 2$, we have at once that $\Bbb R^m\setminus\widetilde{B}\left(a,\frac1n\right)\subseteq\Bbb R^m\setminus\{a\}$ for each $n\ge 2$ and hence that

$$\bigcup_{n\ge 2}\left(\Bbb R^m\setminus\widetilde{B}\left(a,\frac1n\right)\right)\subseteq\Bbb R^m\setminus\{a\}\,.$$

In the other direction element-chasing works. If $x\in\Bbb R^m\setminus\{a\}$, then $x\ne a$, so there is a $k\ge 2$ such that $\frac1k<\|x-a\|$. But then

$$x\in\Bbb R^m\setminus\widetilde{B}\left(a,\frac1k\right)\subseteq\bigcup_{n\ge 2}\left(\Bbb R^m\setminus\widetilde{B}\left(a,\frac1n\right)\right)\,,$$

so

$$\Bbb R^m\setminus\{a\}\subseteq\bigcup_{n\ge 2}\left(\Bbb R^m\setminus\widetilde{B}\left(a,\frac1n\right)\right)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{multline}
\bigcup_{k\ge2}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \tilde{B}(a,1/k)\right)=\bigcup_{k\ge2}^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\cap \tilde{B}(a,1/k)^c\right)=\mathbb{R}^n\cap\left(\bigcup_{k\ge2}^{\infty}\tilde{B}(a,1/k)^c\right)\\=\mathbb{R}^n\cap\left(\bigcap_{k\ge2}^{\infty}\tilde{B}(a,1/k)\right)^c=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\left(\bigcap_{k\ge2}^{\infty}\tilde{B}(a,1/k)\right)
\end{multline}
Now $a\in \tilde{B}(a,1/k)$ for all $k\in\{2,3,\cdots\}$. For any $b\neq a$, there exists $m\in\{2,3,\cdots\}$, such that $m>\frac{1}{|b-a|}$. Then $b\not\in\tilde{B}(a,1/m)$. Hence $\bigcap_{k\ge2}^{\infty}\tilde{B}(a,1/k)=\{a\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the complementary, you can see that what you want to prove is equivalent to
$$\bigcap\limits_{n\geq2}^{\infty}\tilde{B}(a,\frac{1}{n}) = \{a\}$$

which is easier to prove.